# LinqToLdap, at localhost work fine, but host at IIS server return error

Tags: sql-server-2008, asp.net-mvc-4, ldap

Is weird that when hosting at localhost, I can get list of AD from the server, but when host at server 2008 R2, it return error, I using LinqToLDAP, any idea where actually goes wrong?

```
            var config = new LdapConfiguration();
            config.ConfigureFactory(Server).ProtocolVersion(3);
            config.MaxPageSizeIs(Size);

            using (HostingEnvironment.Impersonate()) //solved issue for firefox and safari
            {
                using (var context = new DirectoryContext(config))
                {
                    context.Log = Console.Out;
                    var user = context.Query<ActiveDirectory>();

                    var result = (from m in user
                                  select m).ToList();
                    return result;
                }
            }
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, found the answer, after search through google and play around a bit with the code, figure out that I need to pass in the network credential to make it work

Comment: @SeOng11 can you explain how you did this?

Answer (score 0):

This is the code that work wells in my current system, feel free to study through

**WebConfig**

```
<add key="LdapServer" value="yourADserverName" />
<add key="LdapSize" value="totalpagesziereturn" />
<add key="CreName" value="yourdomainuserid" />
<add key="CrePass" value="yourpassword" />
<add key="CreDomain" value="yourdomain" />
```

**AD.cs**

```
    private int Size = Convert.ToInt32(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["LdapSize"]);
    private string Server = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["LdapServer"];
    private NetworkCredential UserCredential = new NetworkCredential(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["CreName"], ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["CrePass"], ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["CreDomain"]);

    /// <summary>
    /// Get all user from active directory
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public IEnumerable<ActiveDirectory> GetActiveDirectory()
    {
        var config = new LdapConfiguration();
        config.ConfigureFactory(Server).ProtocolVersion(3).UsePort(389).AuthenticateAs(UserCredential);
        config.MaxPageSizeIs(Size);

        using (HostingEnvironment.Impersonate()) //solved issue for firefox and safari
        {
            using (var context = new DirectoryContext(config))
            {
                context.Log = Console.Out;
                var user = context.Query<ActiveDirectory>();

                var result = (from m in user
                              select m).ToList();
                return result;
            }
        }
    }
```